# Science Fiction book about alien species destroying earth with asteroids

Tags: story-identification

In the 70s I read this SF book about an alien species destroying earth using asteroids from the astroid belt between Mars and Jupiter. It was done by 2 physicists and was presenting the case that earth should be very cautious about broadcasting itself into Space. That species would be very xenophobic and not tolerate competition from another technologically advanced species. Any help would be appreciated in locating the title of this book.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Sounds a little like Footfall by Larry Niven and Jerry Pournelle but that was an Invasion by aliens not the destruction of the earth...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footfall - it's also from 1985 not the 70:s

Comment: Likewise, Gregory Benford's [Galactic Center Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Center_Saga) doesn't get into asteroids until the 1980s.

Comment: "It was done by 2 physicists" Does "it" refer to destroying the Earth with asteroids, or writing a book about Earth being destroyed by asteroids?

Comment: That sounds somewhat like *The Armageddon Inheritance* by David Weber, in which a xenophobic species did use asteroids to try to wipe out Earth. However it was from 1993, and there were no "two Physicists" involved. It was the second book in the "Dahak" series

Answer (score 3):

Hi folks thanks for all your suggestions. The name of the book I was looking for was “ The Killing Star” by George Zebrowski and Charles Pellegrino. Sorry it was published in 1995 instead of the 70s. My mistake but I'm glad I was able to retrieve this title from my aged brain. It was a great story and one that was haunting me for a number of reasons. Especially when considering that meeting an alien race may not go the way we think. Check it out, here is a link from wikipedia.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Killing_Star
thank you,
Wayne